# Perl & Bash : FIND regexp

Tags: regex, perl, bash, find, sh

here's my problem :

I have a perl script that searches some Linux files for me.
File names are like this :

```
shswitch_751471_126.108.216.254_13121
```

the problem is that

```
13121
```

is an id randomly increased.
I'm trying, since this morning to search for the right regexp, but i can't find it! Please, could you help?

Here's what i have :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
$dir = "/opt/exploit/dev/florian/scan-allied/working-dir/";
$adresse ="751471" ; 
$ip =  "126.108.216.254";
$tab=`find $dir -type f -name \"$dir_$adresse_$ip_*\"`; 
print $tab;
```

i even tried

```
    $tab=`find $dir -type f -name \"$dir_$adresse_$ip_[0-9]{1}\"`;
```

But perl won't listen to me :(

Comment: You forgot to match the "shswitch".  Add a * to the front as well, and remember that this is *not* a regular expression match but a glob, which is very different.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

```
$tab=`find $dir -type f -name \"$dir_$adresse_$ip_*\"`;
```

with

```
$tab=`find $dir -type f -name \"${dir}_${adresse}_${ip}_*\"`;
```

Comment: Thank you both, yeah i forgot i was already in the $dir so i removed it.
Now i have : 
$tab=`find $dir -type f -name \"shswitch_${adresse}_${ip}_*\"`;
Works well ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have included `$dir` in the filename being passed to `find`.

You perhaps wanted to say:

```
$tab=`find $dir -type f -name \"shswitch_${adresse}_${ip}_*\"`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Uhhh. If You use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) then You do not really need to call `find(1)`! If You use [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/lib/File/Find.pm) module then You can have an even better `find` without the external call. Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "/opt/exploit/dev/florian/scan-allied/working-dir/";
my $addresse ="751471" ; 
my $ip =  "126.108.216.254";
my $re = "shswitch_${addresse}_${ip}_\d+";

sub wanted {
    /^$re$/ and -f $_ and print "$_\n";
}

find \&wanted, $dir;
```

This will print all matching files.

You can use `find2perl` utility to convert a complete `find` command line to the `wanted` function!

For

```
find2perl /opt/exploit/dev/florian/scan-allied/working-dir -type f -name \"shswitch_751471_126.108.216.254_${ip}_*\"
```

The following code is presented:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
    eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
        if 0; #$running_under_some_shell

use strict;
use File::Find ();

# Set the variable $File::Find::dont_use_nlink if you're using AFS,
# since AFS cheats.

# for the convenience of &wanted calls, including -eval statements:
use vars qw/*name *dir *prune/;
*name   = *File::Find::name;
*dir    = *File::Find::dir;
*prune  = *File::Find::prune;

sub wanted;



# Traverse desired filesystems
File::Find::find({wanted => \&wanted}, '/opt/exploit/dev/florian/scan-allied/working-dir');
exit;


sub wanted {
    my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid);

    (($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid) = lstat($_)) &&
    -f _ &&
    /^"shswitch_751471_126\.108\.216\.254__.*"\z/s
    && print("$name\n");
}
```